# In material UI, how do I center a Button in the middle of my Grid item?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, alignment, center

I'm using Material UI's Grid with my React 16.13.0 application.  I want to center the content of a button in the middle of my row.  So I came up with this

center: {
    alignItems: "center",
    width: "100%",
  },
  halfRow: {
    width: "50%",
  },
...

```
      <Grid item className={classes.halfRow}>
        <Button size="medium" onClick={startMission} className={classes.center}>
          <Grid container direction="row" spacing={1} style={{ width: "100%", alignItems: "center" }}>
            <Grid item>
              <PlayCircleFilledIcon />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>START</Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Button>
      </Grid>
```

However, this isn't doing the job.  The button seems to be aligning to the left ...

[image]

What's the right style that I should be applying to get everything to center in the middle of the cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grid takes in [`justify` and `alignItems` as a prop](https://material-ui.com/api/grid/#props) which you can pass to center your content

```
 <Grid item className={classes.halfRow}>
    <Button size="medium" onClick={startMission} className={classes.center}>
      <Grid container direction="row" spacing={1} alignItems={'center'} justify={'center' }style={{ width: "100%" }}>
        <Grid item>
          <PlayCircleFilledIcon />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>START</Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Button>
  </Grid>
```